# Why I am not able to register user info to firebase in SwiftUI App?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have register screen and I am not able to register user info to firebase,
I put user info on simulator, but it just hold on on screen, and no any change on firebase, I guess maybe there is missed points on

> CreateUser

function, any idea?

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct Register: View {
  @State var name = ""
  @State var about = ""
   
  @Binding var show : Bool

  var body: some View {
   VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 3){
          
              TextField("Name",text:self.$name)
                .padding()
         
             
              TextField(" about", text: self.$about)
                .padding()
           

   if self.loading{
                    
                    HStack{
                      
                      Spacer()
                      
                      Indicator()
                      
                      Spacer()
                    }
                  }
                    
                  else{
               
                Button {
                   
                  if self.name != "" && self.about != "" {
                              
                    self.loading.toggle()
                    CreateUser(name: self.name, about: self.about) { (status) in
                                
                        if status{
                                  
                          self.show.toggle()
                           
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    else{
                              
                    self.alert.toggle()
                       
                    }
                } label: {
                  Text("Next")
                    .padding()
  
                }
              }
}
```

**user:**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase


func CreateUser(name: String,about : String, completion : @escaping (Bool)-> Void){
   
  let db = Firestore.firestore()
   
  let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
   
  let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
   
       
      db.collection("users").document(uid!).setData(["name":name,"about":about, "uid":uid!]) { (err) in
         
        if err != nil{
           
          print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
          return
        }
         
        completion(true)
         
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
         
        UserDefaults.standard.set(name, forKey: "UserName")
         
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)
      }
    }
```

Comment: To be able (the title) or not able, that is the question.

Comment: Did you get any error? Does the completion handler get called?

Comment: @burnsi, I am not get error, but user not register on firestore, I don't know what I missed

Comment: You should try to narrow this issue down. Try setting breackpoints. e.g. at this line 'completion(true)'. Does it get called? Do the variables contain the data you expect?

Comment: This is not a reproducible example, so how should i know? And you are not providing any information about the behaviour of your application.